# Make a Linq-to-SQL Generated User Class Inherit from MembershipUser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, membershipuser

I am currently building a custom Membership Provider for my Asp.net MVC website.  I have an existing database with a Users table and I'm using Linq-to-Sql to automatically generates this class for me.

What I would like to do is have this generated User class inherit from the MembershipUser class so I can more easily use it in my custom Membership Provider in methods such as GetUser.  I already have all the necessary columns in the table.

Is there any way to do this?  Or am I going about this the completely wrong way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually code generation tools creates so called partial classes, like:

```
public partial class User
{
    // class definition here
}
```

This means that you can extend definition of that class somewhere within the same namespace like that:

```
public partial class User: MembershipUser
{
    // if MembershipUser doesn't have parameterless constructor then you need
    // to add here one
}
```

And then you'll have User class inheriting from MembershipUser.

Comment: I think this works, but now I'm actually questioning whether or not I need to implement a Membership Provider.

Comment: It depends on whether or not you need to use that specific User table. In my opinion if you have some thousands of users there already and you can't migrate them then you don't have much choice.
But if it is a new project then I'd prefer existing provider...

Comment: Hi  - I'm wanting to do the same thing in my project but I'm wondering how you go about mapping some of the inherited readonly properties such as IsLockedOut?

Comment: @Stephen: almost all properties of the of the `MembershipUser` class are virtual, so you can override them with your implementation.

Comment: @Regent forgive me if I'm missing something obvious but if I'm overriding a readonly property, I'm unable to add a Set accessor. For me to map a property with Linq it needs BOTH get and set.

Comment: @Regent I think I've sorted it be using the new keyword instead of overriding the properties. I've got quite a bit of code to modify before I can test it fully.